# Go equivalent of PHP's 'implode'

Tags: php, go, implode

What is the Go equivalent of PHP's '[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In the standard library: `strings.Join`

```
func Join(a []string, sep string) string
```

http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent about half an hour searching for this and stackoverflow got me the answer in less than 5 minutes! OTOH, I now feel a bit dumb to not have browsed through the "strings" package documentation.

Answer (score 13):

[Join](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) in the *strings* library. It requires the input array to be strings only (since Go is strongly typed).

Here is an example from the manual:

```
s := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz"}
fmt.Println(strings.Join(s, ", "))
```

Answer (score 7):

```
s := []string{"this", "is", "a", "joined", "string\n"};
strings.Join(s, " ");
```

Did this help you?

Answer (score 4):

As i remember, PHP don't have strict typing.
Probably not worst idea to use something like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Implode(glue string, args ...interface{}) string {
    data := make([]string, len(args))
    for i, s := range args {
        data[i] = fmt.Sprint(s)
    }
    return strings.Join(data, glue)
}

type S struct {
    z float64
}

func main() {

    v := Implode(", ", 1, "2", "0.2", .1, S{});
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```